# How can I render mermaid diagrams of type C4 in asciidoctor?

Tags: asciidoctor, mermaid, c4

I am currently trying to render mermaid C4 diagrams using asciidoctor. Mermaid itself can be rendered using asciidoctor. The following example is working as expected.

```
[mermaid,test]
....
timeline
    title History of Social Media Platform
    2002 : LinkedIn
    2004 : Facebook
         : Google
    2005 : Youtube
    2006 : Twitter
....
```

This is my try to render C4 and the result:

```
[mermaid]
....
C4Context
    Person(Customer, "Member")
    Person(Ops, "Ops")
....
```

[image]

Is an include necessary for C4 where you get the C4Context from? My feeling is that this is missing.

Comment: Offtopic, but: I didnt know what mermaid was when reading the title, I was super curious to see what a "mermaid diagram" was.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Mermaid docs](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/c4.html):

```
C4 Diagram: This is an experimental diagram for now. The syntax and
properties can change in future releases. Proper documentation will be
provided when the syntax is stable.
```

The problem is likely that the Asciidoctor dependency you're using to render Mermaid diagrams is using an older version of Mermaid without C4 support.

The [Kroki site](https://kroki.io/) supports Mermaid C4 today, so you might try using [`asciidoctor-kroki`](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-kroki) instead of your current dependency.